# Merge each row above parent with parent/children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table that has a column to the left (parent classes) and columns/rows to the right (children classes). The first column spans several rows while the ones to the right do not. I am attempting to merge each row that is above a parent into the parent below it. Example: Subtotal above Group 1 merged with Group 1 instead of its own row. A little weird to explain so here is my jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/khemikal/ry5p4842/

Here is my function:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".parent").each(function(index, element) {
      var subTotal1 = 0;
      var subTotal2 = 0;
      var subTotal3 = 0;
      var numRows = parseInt($(this).attr("rowspan"));
      var firstRow = $(this).parent();
      var currentRow = firstRow;
      for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        subTotal1 += parseInt($(currentRow.children(".child")[0]).text());
        subTotal2 += parseInt($(currentRow.children(".child")[1]).text());
        subTotal3 += parseInt($(currentRow.children(".child")[2]).text());
        currentRow = currentRow.next("tr");
      }
      firstRow.before('<tr><td></td><td class="sub0">Sub Total</td><td class="sub1">' + subTotal2 + '</td><td class="sub2">' + subTotal3 + '</td></tr>');
    });
  });
```

Any help or advice on achieving this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken your code and simply rearranged it.

I've placed the `tr` at the end, however, this can easily be moved back to the top.

What you were wanting to do was expand the group's rowspan. Since you already have the `numRows` variable, I simply added 1 to it and reapplied it to the group.

**Edit** to make it apply to multiple groups, we have to determine the `lastRow` of each group. I've done this with the named variable. Now, we can ensure that we append the subtotal to the last row before we increment the row's `rowspan` value.

https://jsfiddle.net/vhzjwxkt/

Comment: almost on par with with I am aiming to achieve, perhaps this larger example? https://jsfiddle.net/khemikal/r5xm9act/77/

Comment: Do you *need* the subtotal row to be at the top of each group? Or is the bottom acceptable?

Comment: Got it! Updating my answer now

Answer (score 1):

I'd leave a comment but I don't have enough rep yet for that.

I think you need to provide more info. I'm not sure why you would use .before if you're trying to place it in a specific spot. I'm also not sure why you would be organizing a parent child structure this way. If it were up to me to organize it, I would use data attributes to group it together, or some other attribute (since this is outside a normal DOM parent child relationship).

It sounds like you need to loop through the rows, not the parents. At that point, I would organize the parent > child structure based on the order of the rows using .hasClass to check.

Give me more info and I'll try to help, I'll revise this answer.